# Cache redirect for CloudFront but pass unique query string parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm try to get the following behavior to work for Cloudfront Caching.

```
cloudfronturl.com/path?code=1234 -> Cache Miss 302 redirect to abc123.com?code=1234
cloudfronturl.com/path?code=1235 -> Cache Hit 302 redirect to abc123.com?code=1235
```

Right now, I have it caching the redirect, but it isn't forwarding the query string and is behaving as followed:

```
cloudfronturl.com/path?code=1234 -> Cache Miss 302 redirect to abc123.com?code=1234 (as expected)
cloudfronturl.com/path?code=1235 -> Cache Hit 302 redirect to abc123.com?code=1234 (wrong query parameter value for code)
```

I am basically always forwarding any request to that specific domain, but the value of code can change. There are some option query string parameters that I want to cache so they go to a different domain like below:

```
cloudfronturl.com/path?code=1234&country=CA -> Cache Miss 302 redirect to abc123.ca?code=1234
cloudfronturl.com/path?code=1235&country=MX -> Cache Miss 302 redirect to abc123.mx?code=1235
```

Is there a way to get Cloudfront to behave this way, or am I always going to have to forward my request to my redirect lambda since I want to forward the unique value.

Comment: IIRC under cache behavior there is a toggle to include query strings with cache, but for this specifically you might need lambda@edge.

Comment: Yea, I am forwarding the request to lambda@edge so that works. Trying to avoid unnecessary invocations but not sure if this is possible. I do have that setting set for including query strings in cache, but I think that is what is returning the wrong value for the code query string.